# vb.net c# static event?

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, dll

I have a plugin that creates an object that has an event.  Is there a way for a seperate class to monitor this event, even though it does not have control of the object?

For example, I have a plugin that calls an object that uploads some data.  When the data is uploaded, the event is triggered to say that this is so.  In my client app, I want this to be notified when this event triggers so that it can do something.

The plugin and client will be in C#, and the event class is written in VB.net.

Would it simply be a case of the object notifying the plugin, and in turn, the plugin notifying the client app?

Is this possible?

Thanks.

EDIT (in response to request for code):

The code is fairly simple, it will be a case of in the DLL:

```
Object O = new Object();
O.CompleteEvent += (BLAH BLAH);
O.Run();
```

Now when run completes, it will trigger the CompleteEvent.

I want it to be noticed that this event has triggered within a completely different assembly that does not have the O object.  The new assembly can monitor the event, however it will be outside the scope of the O object.  I hope i'm explaining this okay?

As mentioned earlier, would it simply be a case of the dll then notifying the client assembly that the run is complete?

Comment: can you provide more details (e.g. some code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events can be static or instance, just like any other class members. And you can subscribe static and instance methods to either type.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't used VB.net at all, until 10 minutes ago.  I didn't realise that it should be shared and not static!